# How does recording to Stream work since the length is not known in advance?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, stream, uwp

I'm trying to work with real time media input, and for that am trying to understand how can methods that record to streams (such as [StartRecordToStreamAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture#Windows_Media_Capture_MediaCapture_StartRecordToStreamAsync_)) work, since they don't know the length of the input at the start, while file types like WAV need that information before the actual data.

To be clear, I *can* understand how the methods that save to file work - they, presumably, just fill in that information later. But when feeding a stream - how do they solve that?

Comment: That documentation does say "to a **random access** stream" so presumably that code could also fill in the blanks later.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That sounds right. But would imply that if the stream is interrupted, the data may be corrupt. (Not impossible, of course.)

Comment: That may be. I have no idea really, I just read the documentation you linked to and gave my 2 cents of comment. I have no idea how the recording would handle these things other than that I understand quite easily how it would do this if there is simply a packet-by-packet format with a terminator instead.

Comment: It depends on the streaming protocol ... for http-live-streaming ( HLS ) the media is broken down into 6 second clips which are generated by the sending server as a series of retrievable files ... a manifest file is produced by sender and repeatedly read by the receiving client which list these files as URLs ... this works great for live events where there is no concept of length ... on receiving side it parses each 6 second download and stitches it into a seamless media stream for audio rendering or recording ... HLS uses AAC however for a WAV output file you seek and update length post facto

Answer (score 0):

Only they know exactly how they solve that, but a reasonable assumption is that they write the audio data to the output stream leaving the size blank, and when the recording is done, they `seek` to the beginning of the file, and update the size.

If you read the documentation carefully you will note that it says:

> Starts recording to a random-access stream

And that's almost certainly because they need to be able to seek to the start to update the header.